# Qmake does not find a file still autocomplete shows it

Tags: compiler-errors, qmake

Using QtCreator on Windows, qmake does not find file:

```
#include <glib/galloca.h>
```

my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0" \
               "C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include" \
               "C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib"
```

But if I type the line `#include <glib/ga>` the auto complete does show me the file name "galloca.h" so I don't know why the compiler says "file not found". The file is not in the project directory, but is this problematic?

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, `#include` works relative to `INCLUDEPATH` and both are combined into a single path string and passed to compiler. You use absolute directory path in `INCLUDEPATH`, thus the complete file path is

`C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\include\glib-2.0\glib\galloca.h`

To solve your problem you have to ether use

`C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib` + `#include <galloca.h>`

or

`C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0` + `#include <glib/galloca.h>`

Your IDE probably scan all directories recursively and suggests any file name from there but this information is not used during compilation.